# How to remove the remains of python 3.7?

Tags: python, uninstallation

I have accidentally removed several parts of python and now am trying to start again... The installer says that 57 files are still on my PC and I cannot find them. Does anyone know how to get a copy of the uninstaller? As it should find the remaining files.

Comment: Is this windows? Are you using the default installer from python.org?

Comment: Yes,windows 10 and yes.

Comment: Look under `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`. Or just run the installer again, it should have an option to fix or remove the current install.

Comment: Thanks... the python 3.6 installer managed to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the OS and how Python was installed.

For windows, look under `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` - or just run the installer again, it should have an option to fix or remove the current install.